# How to write facade for Object.assign in scala.js?

Tags: scala.js

I have a library which has structure similar to this

```
class Foo {
  bar(someArgument){
    const baz = {"foobarbaz" : someArgument}
    Object.assign(this, baz)
  }
}
```

intented usage is similar to this

```
var foo = new Foo
foo.bar(myArgument)
```

How can I write a facade around this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript instructions in `bar`:

```
const baz = {"foobarbaz" : someArgument};
Object.assign(this, baz);
```

are basically equivalent to

```
this.foobarbaz = someArgument;
```

Therefore, you can simply type `Foo` as:

```scala
@js.native
@JSGlobal
class Foo extends js.Object {
  def foobarbaz: js.UndefOr[TypeOfSomeArgument] = js.native

  def bar(someArgument: TypeOfSomeArgument): Unit = js.native
}
```

If `TypeOfSomeArgument` varies from one use of `Foo` to the other, you can simply put it as a type parameter of `Foo`:

```scala
class Foo[TypeOfSomeArgument] ...
```

If you vary the `TypeOfSomeArgument` over time for the same *instance* of `Foo`, then you're in trouble. You'll have to use `Any` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
class Foo extends js.Object {
  def bar(someArgume: js.Any): Unit = {
    val baz = js.Dynamic.literal("foobarbaz" -> someArgument)
    js.Object.assign(this, baz)
  }
}
```

This seems to be equivalent to presented one.